# Deleting rows with unwanted values in a Dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to drop rows in a dataframe created using panda in Python. I've tried all the different ways mentioned in different forums but nothing seems to work.

I want to delete the rows with ZipCodes more than 5 digits long, so I saw this as an answer:

```
df = df[len(df.CoulmnName) <5]
df.head
```

and I get Error: "KeyError: False"
And I want to iterate through the dataframe to delete rows where there are values greater than 1 in different columns. This is what I tried:

```
for x in cleandata4bestdeal.columns:
if x[line] > 1:
   df.drop(df[line])
```

and it doesn't work. I want to iterate through the column headers to remove the rows with values that are not 1's or 0's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len(df.ZipCode)` is going to give you the *column length*, not the length of each row. If you want the latter, you'll need to perform the `str.len` operation on it -

```
mask = df.ZipCode.astype(str).str.len() <= 5  # retain zipCodes with 5 or less digits
```

Now, with the mask, you can filter out rows you don't wish to keep:

```
df = df.loc[mask]  # df = df[mask]
```

Comment: I did what you wrote but it only gave me the column header as an output, Idk why?

Comment: @israabuhasna Maybe because you don't have any zips <= 5? Can you post some of your data?

Comment: Nevermind it worked, so I can use this to iterate over the column headers with the condition that non of the values go above 1?

Comment: @israabuhasna Iteration? Nah you don't need to iterate. Just `df = df[mask]` will remove all rows you don't need.

Comment: @Coldspeed Yeah but now I only want 1's or 0's in the columns after ZipCode. So i want to iterate through the column names to delete any wrong data rows:
clmlst = df.columns.tolist()
for x in clmlst[2,:]:
    df = df[(df[x] <= 1)]

I'm still getting errors

Comment: @israabuhasna You don't need iteration! Open a new question with your data and expected output, and I'll show you how.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I updated the question to include a link to the picture. The link is the blue sentence.

Comment: @israabuhasna Your zip code was loaded in as a float? No, that's wrong. When using `read_csv`, you need to specify the `dtype` for it. Please open a new question. I won't ask again.

Answer (score 1):

By using `.str.len()`

```
df[df.zip.astype(str).str.len()<5]
Out[336]: 
    zip
0  1111
2  1111
3  2222
4  3333
```

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'zip':[1111,111111,1111,2222,3333]})
```